# How can I use a comparison operator in a DELETE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM tableA a
WHERE 0 = (SELECT b.quantity 
           FROM tableB b
           WHERE a.id=b.id)
```

This is a example query, but i need to say if i can use the `comparison operator` = after the `WHERE`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The syntax for this varies.  MySQL is different from SQLite is different from SQL Server is different from Oracle is different from PostGreSQL is different from...................

Comment: The SQL documentation for your particular DBMS should have the answer for you.

Comment: Each DBMS has its own rules, give a look in the documentation.

Comment: (A) Tag your DBMS. (B) Simply try it... or even read the docs. There is no need to ask this.

Comment: Sorry, i use PostgreSQL. I need to delete all the row that have quantity (that is in tableB) = 0

Comment: And? Did you try this code? What happened?

Comment: @FedericoMariano, Try my answer, may this helps you.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: "*Can I use a comparison operator after WHERE*" - yes, that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE Id IN(SELECT id FROM tableB WHERE quantity=0)
```

Comment: @FedericoMariano, If it's fine, then accept the answer, this may help someone.